# Get Null record in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one query written in postgresql

```
select components.* 
  from sg_paycomponents components  
       left outer join tblextempinfo info 
          on info.c_company=components.company
 where components.type ='RECURRING-AMOUNTS' 
   and components.cid not in (
                              select components 
                                from sg_recurringamounts 
                               where employee =400
                             )
   and info.employee=400;
```

this query giving me all record but i want that in sg_paycomponents table i should get that record also where type = 'RECURRING-AMOUNTS' and company is null my query is not giving me if company is null can any one plz help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
and info.employee=400
```

To:

```
and (info.employee=400 OR info.employee IS NULL)
```